# logo uploaded through backend doesn't come through (on my environment)

Tags: image

I've got a logo uploaded through the backend, I've got the file locally & can see it on the craft login screen and the backend.

Colleague can see it fine on the front end on a template, but I cannot.

Loading it in on the front end with: `{{ craft.rebrand.logo.url }}`

It just seems to timeout while the page is being loaded:
[image: network tab]

Storage folder is 777'd recursively, I presume it's loading it through that (due to the /cpresources/ path)

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any errors with devMode on?

Comment: Turned out it wasn't, but I've fixed it thanks to that!
though that wasn't the issue. my colleague had used a  local server name 1 char different to mine. The domain I was using didn't match the "siteUrl" param in the general config.

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague had used a  local server name 1 char different to mine.

The domain I was using didn't match the "siteUrl" param in the general config.

The image was loading in with a different domain to what I was on.